# Vbulletin override default template

Tags: php, vbulletin

I want to override threadbit template with my plugin.

The straight solution I found is that I can replace the threadbit template with my custom template. But, I am not getting how to do it.

If this is not the way to do so, then what is the right solution for that problem.